# First depiction of Einstein's "Train and Embankment" thought experiment with relevant 3 "train constituents" shown individually labelled (A', M', B')

Tags: special-relativity, history, specific-reference

The principal source of the widely known ["Train and Embankment" thought experiment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein%27s_thought_experiments#Trains,_embankments,_and_lightning_flashes) is -- [by all appearances](https://einsteinpapers.press.princeton.edu/%7EsearchResults?searchMode=app&searchParam-depth=fulltext&searchParam-versions=all&searchParam-years=%7B%22operator%22%3A%22%22%7D&searchParam-sort=date&searchParam-terms=embankment&searchParam-start=20&searchParam-page=25) as well as [by expert judgement](https://einsteinpapers.press.princeton.edu/vol6-doc/446) -- Albert Einstein's booklett [*"On the Special and the General Theory of Relativity (A Popular Account)"*](https://einsteinpapers.press.princeton.edu/vol6-doc/448); originally in [German (1917), with translations](https://einsteinpapers.press.princeton.edu/vol6-doc/445) appearing soon afterwards.

(Earlier works by other authors may have already described somewhat similar setups, for instance [D. F. Comstock (1910)](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/The_Principle_of_Relativity_(Comstock)); but by now, Einstein's account has surely become the most popular.)

In Einstein's booklett, the first and definitive mentioning of *"the train"* appears in [chap. IX (*"The Relativity of Simultaneity"*)](https://gutenberg.org/cache/epub/5001/pg5001-images.html#ch9); where we find the corresponding *"Fig. 1"*:

[image: A. Einstein, On SR and GR (A popular account), Fig. 1]

> *"We suppose a very long train travelling along the rails with the constant velocity v and in the direction indicated in Fig. 1."*

Notably, *"the embankment"* had already been introduced in the preceding [chap. VIII (*"On the Idea of Time in Physics"*)](https://gutenberg.org/cache/epub/5001/pg5001-images.html#ch8):

> *"Lightning has struck the rails on our railway embankment at two places A and B far distant from each other."*

Also, a more detailed description of *"the train"*, in relation to the two places (also: in the sense of constituents) of the railway embankment, A and B, mentioned earlier, continues (only) in [chap. X (*"On the Relativity of the Conception of Distance"*)](https://gutenberg.org/cache/epub/5001/pg5001-images.html#ch10):

> *"two particular points on the train -- e.g. the middle of the first and of the hundredth carriage --  travelling along the embankment with the velocity v [...] call A′ and B′ the two points on the train [...] In the first place we require to determine the points A and B of the embankment which are just being passed by the two points A′ and B′ at a particular time t -- judged from the embankment [...] determined by applying the definition of time given in Section VIII."*

But this description appearing only in chap. X is remarkable because: Einstein managed to write and to conclude the entire preceding chapter IX without any explicit mentioning of the designations A' nor B' at all !
Evidently, there are no labels A' nor B' shown in *"Fig. 1"* of chap. IX (which is the only figure in chap. IX) !

The purpose and the merits or consequences of this particular way of presentation may surely be debated -- elsewhere. My request, which is spelled out below, is merely based on my observation that it seems possible, even straightforward, and at least for some authors desirable, to add the labels A' and B' appropriately into a depiction of the "Train-and-Embankment" setup, namely labelling the corresponding points, a.k.a. constituents, of the train; in addition to the label M' which already appears in *"Fig. 1"*; as shown for instance in this picture (which was not produced by myself, btw.):

[image: Just some image of the TETE containing the labels A' and B']

Therefore

**My specific-reference request:**

Which is **the earliest reference** of a picture of the "Train and Embankment" thought experiment setup in which the relevant three constituents of the train are shown and explicitly individually labelled ?

(The specific designations A' and B' along with Einstein's given M' for these three relevant constituents of the train might be considered the most obvious. But I'm looking for the earliest reference to a picture with any explicit individual labelling regardless of any particular designations; as long as the designations and corresponding labels of all three relevant constituents of the train and of all three relevant constituents of the embankment are all distinct.)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on the history of science and math stack exchange: https://hsm.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Dale: _"I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on the history of science and math stack exchange [...]"_ -- Thanks for the heads-up. Do you agree that strictly all questions on [specific-reference] belong on the history of science (since, generally, there's a date attached to a specific references), and to you strictly vote accordingly ? Before my question might be closed for good, would I get a warning and the chance to (try to) convert to a [resource-recommendation] question, remaining on PSE ?

Comment: Request for reference questions are pretty tightly controlled here, but no, not all such questions belong on HSM. This specific one does, because the criterion for your requested reference is merely that it is the first. That is a historical question which belongs on HSM.

Comment: @Dale: _"This specific one does [...] belong on HSM [...], because the criterion for your requested reference is merely that it is the first."_ -- This assessment presents a misunderstanding (or possibly a misrepresentation?), since the OP is not requesting plainly **_the first_ reference**; but instead the first reference with certain extensively described and physics-motivated content. If a [specific-reference] question is, or will be, correctly answerable by only one such reference, which therefore also is **the first match**, then the guidance should warn against attempts to move to HSM.

Comment: I am not sure why you are arguing. Saying it belongs on HSM is not an insult, I am saying that HSM is the best place for you to get an answer to your question. I am an acknowledged expert in relativity, and not only do I not know the answer to your question, I don’t even have a guess who would be the most likely author. HSM people, on the other hand, that is exactly what interests them. Tracing an idea back to its roots is exactly what they do. Your question isn’t a bad question, but it doesn’t fit this site. It fits HSM

Comment: @Dale: _"I am not sure why you are arguing."_ -- I appreciate your tenacity. _"Saying it belongs on HSM is not an insult, "_ -- I'm not so sure ... Anyways, closing/removing a question with explicit physics relevance from PSE is. Adding the tag [history] here is fair, right ? _"a guess who would"_ -- Well, v. Laue, Born, Synge, Rindler ... Norton, Gourgoulhon, Brown don't, correct ? The earliest I'd know (from arxive) **who does** isn't even 20th century, and not even aware/proud enough of the accomplishment to discuss or even reference it. (How about you?).

Comment: @Dale: _"HSM people"_ -- ... qualify by checking out [history] on PSE, right? So, anticipating the worst case, I prepare for transition to [resource-recommendation]. Gimme a week, or two ...

Comment: I think Dale's point is right. The essence of your question is when was the first time a particular set of symbols was added to a diagram, which has nothing to do with the underlying physics. Einstein might have considered symbols for A' and B' to be superfluous, given that in his accompanying narrative he explicitly states that A' and B' are alongside A and B, so what is there to be confused about?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not a question about the meaning of physics but essentially about when a diagram was first labelled with a particular pair of symbols.