# Searching specific original source of this illustration of the "Train-&-Track" thought experiment (which decisively differs from Einstein's drawing)

Tags: special-relativity, specific-reference

I'm trying to ascertain **the original source** and author of this picture:

[image: Picture from J. M. Bird's book, illustrating "An Einsteinian Experiment".]

which can be found in [this section (*"An Einsteinian Experiment"*)](https://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/63372/pg63372-images.html#xd29e2128) of

> ***Einstein’s Theories of Relativity and Gravitation***
> *A Selection of Material from the Essays Submitted in the Competition for the EUGENE HIGGINS PRIZE of $5,000*
> compiled and edited, and introductory matter supplied
> **by J. Malcolm Bird,**
> Associate Editor, Scientific American
> New York, Scientific American Publishing Co., Munn & Co., 1921

Related to reasons explained in the [*"Preface"*](https://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/63372/pg63372-images.html#preface) section of this book, it doesn't seem obvious whether [J. Malcolm Bird](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/J._Malcolm_Bird) himself can be credited with having had the idea of this particular way of illustrating (his understanding of) Einstein's "Train-&-Track" thought experiment, perhaps even having drawn the picture himself;
or whether this exact picture (or at least some direct precursor version) has instead been conceived by another author first; originating specifically from one of [the essays from which J. M. Bird's book derived (as listed at the end of the *"Preface"*)](https://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/63372/pg63372-images.html#preface). Therefore

### My question:

Can the picture shown above be originally attributed to J. Malcolm Bird ?
Or does it have another specific original source and author, and was only adapted for the book *Einstein’s Theories of Relativity and Gravitation* ?

---

**Note on originality and scientific importance of this picture from J. M. Bird's book**

The picture I'm asking about, as included in J. M. Bird's book as an illustration of Einstein's "Train-&-Track" thought experiment, and as shown above, has of course some resemblance and correspondence to [Einstein's own illustration](https://einsteinpapers.press.princeton.edu/vol6-trans/286) (see below); and it differs in some respects, some of which might be considered "mere artistic choice".

A remarkable and significant difference, however, is the addition of the labels ${\mathbf A^{\prime}}$ and ${\mathbf B^{\prime}}$ in the picture from J. M. Bird's book (while the labels ${\mathbf A}$, ${\mathbf M}$, ${\mathbf B}$, and ${\mathbf M^{\prime}}$ appear similarly in both pictures).

This addition of labels ${\mathbf A^{\prime}}$ and ${\mathbf B^{\prime}}$ allows to recognize and to discuss

**(1)** a direct, literal correspondence of the items labelled ${\mathbf A}$, ${\mathbf B}$, ${\mathbf M}$ in the picture from J. M. Bird's book to $A$ and $B$ (the two *"points (constituents) of the railway embankment"*) and to $M$ (the *"mid-point between $A$ and $B$"*) as they appear [in Einstein's own explicit definition of "simultaneity"](https://einsteinpapers.press.princeton.edu/vol6-trans/283?highlightText=perceives)

and also, separately

**(2)** a direct, if only almost literal correspondence of the items labelled ${\mathbf A^{\prime}}$, ${\mathbf B^{\prime}}$, ${\mathbf M^{\prime}}$ in the picture from J. M. Bird's book to $A$ and $B$ (the two *"points (constituents) of the railway embankment"*) and to $M$ (the *"mid-point between $A$ and $B$"*) as they appear in Einstein's own explicit definition of "simultaneity".

In contrast, whether the labelling in Einstein's own drawing suggests the correspondence **(1)** is at best questionable (since Einstein refers to ${\mathbf A}$ and ${\mathbf B}$ in his drawing as ***"events"*; and not as *"points of the railway embankment"*** any more); and the correspondence **(2)**, separately from **(1)**, is not recognizable in Einstein's drawing at all:

[image: Einstein's illustration of the "Train-&-Track" thought experiment. Relativity: the Special and General Theory, IX]

The picture from J. M. Bird's book in which I'm interested is therefore relevant

- to our understanding of the notion "event" in the theory of relativity,

specifically

- whether distinct participants (such as those labelled ${\mathbf A}$ and ${\mathbf A^{\prime}}$) may at least in principle be thought as having together (in coincidence) taken part in the same event (in this case: in event $\varepsilon_{(A ~ A^{\prime})}$),
- whether to distinct participants together in one-and-the-same event may at least in principle be attributable distinct individual portions of this event (as distinct individual [*"positions of pointers"*](https://einsteinpapers.press.princeton.edu/vol6-trans/285highlightText=pointers), or more generally "indications"),

and therefore even

- whether [Einstein's own explicit definition of "simultaneity"](https://einsteinpapers.press.princeton.edu/vol6-trans/283?highlightText=perceives) is actually concerned with "simultaneity of events" at all; or ("merely") with "simultaneity of *"positions of pointers"* (or of indications)" of certain pairs of participants.

Comment: This feels like it belongs more on [History of Science and Mathematics stack exchange](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [First depiction of Einstein's "Train and Embankment" thought experiment with relevant 3 "train constituents" shown individually labelled (A', M', B')](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/784020/)

Comment: @march: _"This feels like it belongs more on History of Science and Mathematics stack exchange."_ -- I feel that my question belongs on [Physics StackExchange](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/800789/searching-specific-original-source-of-this-illustration-of-the-train-track-t?noredirect=1#comment1799071_800789), where I put it and it is, foremost for expediency: Variants of the sought picture have appeared in the RT literature even recently. Surely some of **those authors** must already done the requested search ... Also: the tag `specific-reference` is available here.